# Windows 10 Internet randomly disconnecting

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, network-adapter, broadcom

I recently did a Fresh Install of Windows 10 about a week ago now, all was fine up until last night where my internet started randomly disconnecting every 2 minutes and then it eventually spanned out to every 20 minutes, this went on for the rest of the night.

I tried to see if it was just my computer so I ssh'd to another computer on my network and started pinging google while also doing so on my PC, it took 20 minutes for my PC to drop out for 2 seconds while the other computer kept pinging google fine.

I then tried to install the driver that came with my motherboard which still resulted in the same outcome and also downloaded the newest up to date driver from broadcoms website which still ended up with the same outcome.

My friend said he had the same problem with windows 10 when he freshly Installed it but fixed it by installing Windows 8 and then Upgrading to Windows 10, so I did that this morning at around 10am, its now 9:50 and I my PC disconnected for the first time at 9:30 and then again 10 minutes later, both times were for around 2 minutes.

I have looked everywhere for a solution and it seems everyone that has this problem can't find one, my Power Settings are fine and other devices on my network do not Disconnect, I haven't installed anything recently and if so it would be resolved with the fresh install I did today. This literally started happening randomly.

Comment: Have you tried plugging this affected computer to another port in the switch/router/modem it is connected to? It also might be an symptom of a failing port in the network gear... Especially if the other computer (which works ok) is behind the same Internet connection, it shouldn't be the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's either something wrong with your network card or it's a Windows coding error that occurred during installation of Windows 10. However it's more likely a network card error. Try replacing your network card. Depending on your PC brand and type, network card changing will slightly vary but I found this link quite useful: [click here](http://www.wisegeek.com/how-do-i-replace-a-network-card.htm#).

The problem may also be with a small error in the installation of Windows. This isn't Microsoft's fault as the error occurs when the installation is quite bumpy or difficult but it would be unlikely that serious errors would occur and they are a common thing. One problem around the error would be a re-installation of the Windows 10 operating system its self. I found a pretty helpful like right [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/).

Your network service provider can also be to blame too. Try contacting them and alerting them of the problem if it still is not resolved fully by the two above solutions.

There are other things too that include hardware error elsewhere or your system being slightly incompatible with Windows 10 overall but that would mean Windows 10 would hardly work at all then so that is also unlikely. If the problem persists, it may be your network service provider.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll check out these links however my current network adapter is inbuilt on the motherboard, not an external PCI one I would love to think its my ISP but it hasnt happened to any other devices on my network.

Comment: As the OP mentions another system in his network is not affected by the issue, what reasons you have to suspect the ISP?

Comment: Well as I mentioned before, the problem may unlikely be with the ISP but this should be only considered after you have established the fact that it's not an error with your network card (most likely) or the actual software error in the coding that came with the installation of Windows 10 (much less likely, in fact quite rare).